# Excel Hyperlinks change when I move spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet in which I add hyperlinks to files using vba as follows:

```
Sheet1.Cells.Hyperlinks.Add Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), objFile.Path
```

This works fine. But if i move the spreadsheet which has the hyperlinks in it to another folder, all the hyperlinks change relative to the folder where I move the spreadsheet to.

Is there a way to stop this happening and fixing the hyperlinks path.

Thanks

Comment: Where is this code placed? Also what is the objFile? How are you setting it?

Comment: Im not sure that matters as I have just realised that even if I just open a new workbook and manually add a hyperlink. If I then save the workbook it works fine, but once I move the workbook to another folder the hyperlink changes. It works fine in Excel 2003 but in 2007 I get the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the hyperlink full path *formula* rather than the hyperlink object

```
Sub AddHyperlinkFormula()
Dim strMyPath As String, strMyFile As String, strName As String

strMyPath = "C:\Path\to\"
strMyFile = "Workbook.xlsx!"
strName= "Alt Text!"

ActiveCell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & strMyPath & strMyFile & """,""" & strName& """)"
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont want my cell to be a formula though. Is there no way of fixing the path of the hyperlink so it doesnt change?

Comment: What are you hyperlinking? And why are you trying to avoid a formula?

Comment: Im just hyperlinking another spreadsheet. Can you try manually adding a hyperlink to a workbook. Then saving the workbook. If you then move your workbook to a different folder does the hyperlink change and fail? Thanks

Comment: I think I have just solved it. I have just made sure that there is something in Hyperlink Base on workbook properties. This seems to stop Excel from changing the path of hyperlinks when you move the workbook. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JC75: Note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Comment: yet, Raystafarian desserves some credits (and +1) for a nice stab to an unclear issue

Answer (score 0):

The same thing drove me nuts.. '=hyperlink' is not always a choice since it has a 255 maxchar limitation. So the best solution is indeed to set the hyperlink base (which is workbook-specific). Can be done in two ways:

1) File -> Properties -> Summary Tab -> Hyperlink base

2) or with vba `ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(29)`